# Reconnect TCP on EOF in Go

Tags: tcp, go

I have the following:

```
    //In an init func
    if logStashHost != "" {
        lsconn, err = net.Dial("tcp", logStashHost)
    }
    ...
    ToLogStash(rec, lsconn)
```

Then Two functions:

```
func ReadLogStash(conn net.Conn) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 256)
    for {
        _, err := conn.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(buffer)
        }
    }
}

func ToLogStash(r *logrow.Record, conn net.Conn) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    _, err = fmt.Fprintln(conn, string(b))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Where ReadLogStash is a running goroutine. If the other side closes, I get EOF. What would be a good implementation in ReadLogStash to have it attempt to reestablish the connection every X seconds when it gets an EOF?

Comment: what do ToLogStash and ReadLogStack have to do with one another?

Comment: @JimB they are both passed the same conn. The idea is that send are not blocked by reads because of the goroutine. But maybe that doesn't makes sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go has channels for synchronization and communication, use them!

Make your connection in a loop, and have it wait for some sort of message to come back on a channel.

```
...
errCh := make(chan error)
for {
    lsconn, err = net.Dial("tcp", logStashHost)
    // check error!
    go ReadLogStash(lsconn, errCh)
    err = <-errCh
    if err != nil {
        // bad error
        break
    }
    // sleep to backoff on retries?
}
...

func ReadLogStash(conn net.Conn, errCh chan error) {
    _, err := io.Copy(os.Stderr, conn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // a nil error from io.Copy means you reached EOF.
    errCh <- err
}
```

Unless you have more functionality in ReadLogStash, you can probably just use io.Copy inline, and forget the entire function, but this pattern may come in useful for you anyway.

Comment: This will create a bunch of TCP connections though won't it? I just want to have one open at a time...

Comment: But I'll play with a channel, plop the things I want to send on a channel, and then have a single goroutine that handles sending them - will see how that works for me.

Comment: no, this will block on `<-errCh`, which won't have a value until the current connection is closed.

Comment: I know this is old but it's missing the `go` statement at `go ReadLogStash(lsconn, errCh)` otherwise ReadLosgStash is fully executed before the `err = <-errCh`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up going with, a channel was the right direction:

```
if logStashHost != "" {
    lsc = make(chan *logrow.Record)
    go ToLogStash(lsc, logStashHost)
}
...
if lsc != nil {
   lsc <- rec
}
...
func ToLogStash(c chan *logrow.Record, logStashHost string) {
    var lsconn net.Conn
    var enc *json.Encoder
    var err error
    connect := func() {
        for {
            lsconn, err = net.Dial("tcp", logStashHost)
            if err == nil {
                enc = json.NewEncoder(lsconn)
                break
            }
            log.Println(err)
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }
    connect()
    for r := range c {
        err = enc.Encode(r)
        if err != nil {
            lsconn.Close()
            log.Println(err)
            connect()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wroth noting that this doesn't doesn't read, because in this instance I don't need to read. So it seems an error on write is good enough to Close the socket and attempt to start a new one

Comment: It's not a good idea to wait for an error on Write over a TCP connection as your only means to detect it shutting down. In the best case it will take an extra `send` before you get an error (_if_ you have data waiting for that extra send), worst case you're left waiting for a network timeout.