# How to make net.Dial in Go reconnect if connection is lost?

Tags: go

I have an app in Go that's connecting to XMPP host using tcp and then xml Decoder to talk XMPP. How can I make net.Dial reconnect if tcp connection is dropped?

I am getting the following error on my error channel when the connection is dropped:
`write tcp client:port->xmpp_server:5222: write: broken pipe`. However I'm not sure how to properly handle it in my `Dial` function to make it reconnect.

```
// package xmpp
// Conn represents a connection
type Conn struct {
    incoming *xml.Decoder
    outgoing net.Conn
    errchan  chan error
}

// SetErrorChannel sets the channel for handling errors
func (c *Conn) SetErrorChannel(channel chan error) {
    c.errchan = channel
}

// Dial dials an xmpp host
func Dial(host string) (*Conn, error) {
    c := new(Conn)
    var err error

    c.outgoing, err = net.Dial("tcp", host+":5222")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Can't dial %s:5222: %s", host, err)
        return c, err
    }

    // TCP Keep Alive
    err = c.outgoing.(*net.TCPConn).SetKeepAlive(true)
    if err != nil {
        c.errchan <- err
    }
    err = c.outgoing.(*net.TCPConn).SetKeepAlivePeriod(30 * time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        c.errchan <- err
    }

    c.incoming = xml.NewDecoder(c.outgoing)
    log.Printf("Connected to: %s", c.outgoing.RemoteAddr())
    return c, nil
}

// In a separate package
func NewXMPPClient(config) (*Client, error) {
    errchannel := make(chan error)
    connection, err := xmpp.Dial(host)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    connection.SetErrorChannel(errchannel)

    // Do XMPP auth, receive messages, etc...
```

Comment: Reconnecting is not the responsibility of `Dial`; only connecting. The user of `Dial` is responsible for reconnecting intelligently if that's appropriate to the use case.

Comment: I didn't mean net.Dial function, but my own Dial() function in the code above.

Comment: You can't really reconnect from your `Dial` - when `Dial` returns, it's passing ownership of the `Conn` to its caller, so `Dial` shouldn't be doing *anything* with that `Conn` any more or it will cause all sorts of bizarre issues. What happens when you intentionally close the connection? How will Conn know when to reconnect? Should it resend data that was written to it when the connection failed? This doesn't seem like a problem that can or should be solved in this function.

Comment: I need to keep connection open all the time and there's no case when I want to close it intentionally. It shouldn't resend any data, just re-establish the connection. I was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23396415/4833237 but couldn't come up with a way to use it in my case.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's possible "there's no case when I want to close it intentionally". At the very least, eventually your process will exit and it should close its connection gracefully, and not attempt to reopen it.

Comment: Good point. I'll make a note on it.

Comment: With XMPP, you must restart the XML stream when reestablishing the connection.

Comment: Thanks. Figured it out. I was on the right track, just needed to properly close and re-create tcp connection and then auth+re-start listener for xmpp.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I just started to close the current tcp connection on any error in my error channel and re-create both TCP and XMPP (auth+listen) connections.